# I want to predict the no.of updates for a new incident? how to do that in python?

Tags: python, knn, text-classification, naivebayes, workload

I have a data set of n incidents which has some information to it. Information such as description (text is in either english or german) and no.of updates information(in intiger). I want to predict the no.of updates for a new incident regardless of the defined language(german or english).

I just started learnig python. Please suggest the action plan libraies/algortims used in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) and [nltk](https://pypi.org/project/nltk/).

However, @Emil is right. You should probably follow a course or tutorial with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and Jupyter Notebooks or just any other Data Science material.

Comment: Thank you @carlos

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Note that this is a site to help with code and not to help with methodologies. Go to [TowardsDataScience](https://www.towardsdatascience.com) to get a better understanding of Data Science and to [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.com) to learn more about Python.